# Cloudera Express Installation on CentOS 7 (Cluster mode Proof of Concept)

Tags: linux, centos

I want to install cloudera express edition on CentOS in a cluster with four nodes.
Everything seems to run ok and the agents are installed. But when i try to hit the continue button, an error message is displayed preventing me from installing the parcels.

Below a screenshot there is a screenshot attached with the error.

[Cloudera Error with null values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViQ5j.png)

Does anynone faced the same issue as I did? And if yes, could you please described how you solved the problem?

Kind Regards,
Vassilis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of struggling, I did the following steps:

1. I made sure that each virtual machine has the same /etc/hosts file (for some reason, this file is something like a routing table)
2. I edited the /etc/sysconfig/network with the FQDN of the host only and added the following properties (NETWORKING = yes, HOSTNAME=)
3. Run the uname -a command to verify the hostname
4. I disabled the chronyd service in all hosts (systemctl stop chronyd, systemctl disable chronyd)
5. I have installed and enabled the ntpd service in all hosts (systemctl enable ntpd, systemctl start ntpd)
6. configure the swappiness in each host (sysctl vm.swappines=10)
7. Disable Transparent Huge Page Compaction cause it can cause significant performance problems (echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag and echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled). I also created a shell script file which contains these commands and schedule it via crontab.
8. Disabled the selinux by using the following commands (a. vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux
   b. change the SELINUX=enforcing to SELINUX=disabled c. reboot the host)

These were the steps that i did and after a reboot on all hosts i finally achieved to install the cluster successfully.